# Value of select tag inside the td

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I can't get the value of selected option. I always get the whole valau of each option including the disable option

Here's my code in displaying table

```
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs))) {
                                    ?>
      <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['order_item_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo ucfirst(getProductIDFromId($con, $row['product_id'])); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo ucfirst(getProductNameFromId($con, $row['product_id'])); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['rate']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['quantity']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['total']; ?></td>

              <td>


              <select id="discount" name="discount">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Select Discount</option>

               <option>0.3</option>
               <option>0.2</option>

               </select>
             </td>
 <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btnapplydiscount" id="btnapplydiscount" 
data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-whatever="@mdo"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria- 
hidden="true"></i>
```

I will get the value of td[6] through jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.btnapplydiscount').on('click', function() {
            $('#applydiscountmodal').modal('show');
            $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var data = $tr.children("td").map(function(){
                return $(this).text();
            }).get();
            console.log(data);
            $('#apply_discount').val(data[0]);
            $('#value_discount').val(data[6]);
           
        
        });
    });
```

and pass the value to the modal

```
      <div class="modal fade" id="applydiscountmodal" tabindex="-1" aria- 
     labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Apply Discount</h5>
     <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <form action="apply_discount.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <input type="hidden" name="apply_discount" id="apply_discount">
                            <input type="hidden" name="value_discount" id="value_discount">
                            <h4>Do you want to apply discount to this order item?</h4>

                        </div>




                        <div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Close</button>
  <button type="submit" name="applydiscountbtn" class="btn btn-danger">Apply</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and when in the debugging, always get the value of value discount = Select Discount 0.3 0.2
I hope you could help me. Thank you very much

Comment: First of all, IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document, you are violating that basic rule by creating elements with the same ID multiple times in your loop.

Comment: Second, of course you are getting the text of all options, when you just read the _text content_ of the select field (resp. the TD containing it.) The proper way to get a select field's current value is `$(selectElement).val()`.

Comment: You want something like `$('#value_discount').val( $tr.find('select').val() );` or similar here. (If you had more than one select field per row, then that selector would have to be more specific.)

Comment: Alternatively, in the `$tr.find("td").map(` change to check for a select/input, eg `map(function() { return $(this).find("select").length > 0 ? $(this).find("select").val() : $(this).text(); }`